# Como apagar arquivos dentro de uma pasta

Tags: php

Desejo apagar todos os arquivos e subpastas dentro de uma pasta, mas sem apagar a mesma, utilizando PHP.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: (se for unix) ver comando `rm`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eis uma função pronta, postada no próprio [site do PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php#87045)

```
<?php 
/** 
* Recursively delete a directory 
* 
* @param string $dir Nome do diretório 
* @param boolean $deleteRootToo Ponha True se quiser deletar a pasta (nao é seu caso) 
*/ 
function unlinkRecursive($dir, $deleteRootToo) 
{ 
    if(!$dh = @opendir($dir)) 
    { 
        return; 
    } 
    while (false !== ($obj = readdir($dh))) 
    { 
        if($obj == '.' || $obj == '..') 
        { 
            continue; 
        } 

        if (!@unlink($dir . '/' . $obj)) 
        { 
            unlinkRecursive($dir.'/'.$obj, true); 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($dh); 
    if ($deleteRootToo) 
    { 
        @rmdir($dir); 
    } 
    return; 
} 
?>
```

Autor: Jon Hassall

Para usar a função no seu código, basta acrescentar uma linha chamando a função, assim:

```
unlinkRecursive( '/www/luis/public_html/pasta_a_apagar', false );
```

O ponto importante a notar é o uso da supressão (`@`) no `unlink`. Ela é relevante neste caso, pois se trocarmos por `file_exists`, o script pode falhar caso mais de um processo esteja deletando arquivos na pasta.

Answer (score 6):

## PHP 5 ou superior

Para eliminar tudo dentro de determinada diretoria:

```
$dir = "caminho/para/diretoria";
$di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$ri = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

foreach ( $ri as $file ) {
    $file->isDir() ?  rmdir($file) : unlink($file);
}
```

Saber mais sobre as classes [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) e [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php).

---

## Verificações

Devemos sempre ter em atenção alguns detalhes para garântir um correto funcionamento da aplicação. Entre os mesmos verificar:

- Se o caminho fornecido aponta para uma diretoria

  A verificação pode ser rápidamente realizada com a função [`is_dir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php):

  ```
  $dir = "caminho/para/diretoria";

  if (is_dir($dir)) {
    // é uma diretoria
  }
  else {
    // não é uma diretoria
  }
  ```
- Se a diretoria não está vazia

  Podemos verificar fazendo uso do método [`valid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/iterator.valid.php) do iterador:

  ```
  $dir = "caminho/para/diretoria";

  $iterator = new \FilesystemIterator($dir);

  if ($iterator->valid()) {
    // tem coisas lá dentro
  }
  else {
    // vazio, não é preciso fazer nada
  }
  ```

---

## Exemplo

Um exemplo completo seria:

```
/**
 * Apagar Tudo
 * 
 * Remove todos os ficheiros, sub-diretorias e seus ficheiros
 * de dentro do caminho fornecido.
 * 
 * @param string $dir Caminho completo para diretoria a esvaziar.
 */
function apagarTudo ($dir) {

    if (is_dir($dir)) {

        $iterator = new \FilesystemIterator($dir);

        if ($iterator->valid()) {

            $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
            $ri = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

            foreach ( $ri as $file ) {

                $file->isDir() ?  rmdir($file) : unlink($file);
            }
        }
    }
}

apagarTudo("caminho/para/diretoria");
```

Answer (score 0):

Acabei por resolver o meu problema com o seguinte código:

```
<?php
/* Crie uma nome da pasta exemplo: "nome_da_pasta" coloque arquivos dentro,
 * ele vai remover tudo como mostra o script abaixo
 */

/**
 * remover a pasta e tudo centro dele
 */
function ApagaDir($dir) {
  if($objs = glob($dir."/*")){
    foreach($objs as $obj) {
      is_dir($obj)? ApagaDir($obj) : unlink($obj);
    }
  }
  rmdir($dir);
} 

$nome_da_pasta="../public_html";

ApagaDir($nome_da_pasta); 

mkdir("../public_html");
?>
```

Comment: Editei para aprimorar a leitura da resposta. Tinhas dito na pergunta que não querias remover a pasta em si, no entanto a tua solução faz isso mesmo ?!? Se quiseres alterar para não remover a pasta, evitando depois estar a criar a mesma, basta removeres da função `ApagaDir()` a última linha onde se lê `rmdir($dir);`. Assim a pasta em si não é removida e deixas de precisar do `mkdir("../public_html");`

Answer (score -1):

O que é uma pasta php?
Se estivermos em unix, sugiro:

```
rm -rf nome_da_pasta/*
```

**Muito cuidado** com experiências de remoção de pastas recursivamente! 
(isto aplica-se a todas as respostas apresentadas, claro).

Comment: Com `rm -rf` se te enganas no caminho, vais apagar muita coisa. Não é muito _saudável_ utilizar isso da forma que descreves na resposta! Pelo menos completar a mesma com uma verificação!

Comment: @Zuul, Claro! é essa a encomenda (daí o meu aviso)! todas as respostas apresentadas estão a apagar impiedosamente! :)

Comment: Está resolvido ;) Muito obrigado a todos.