# Como apagar todos arquivos jpg dentro de uma pasta com PHP

Tags: php

Tenho diversas pastas com imagens que preciso que, por PHP, ele exclua todos os arquivos .JPG antes de iniciar uma determinada função, sem apagar as subpastas que estão dentro.

Como posso fazer essa função de apagar os JPG sem apagar as subpastas?

A pasta está assim:

```
imagem/01.JPG
imagem/02.JPG
imagem/original/01.JPG
imagem/original/02.JPG
```

quero apagar só os 2 primeiros "imagem/01.JPG e imagem/02.JPG"

Comment: Os arquivos também estão nessas subpastas?

Comment: sim, alterei a pergunta mostrando como está a pasta

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56228/como-apagar-arquivos-dentro-de-uma-pasta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
array_map('unlink', glob("caminho/completo/*.JPG"));
```

O [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.glob.php) vai retornar um array com todos os caminhos possíveis (referente aos arquivos .JPG dentro da pasta indicada).

O [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php) vai aplicar a função `unlink` em cada elemento do array.

O [`unlink`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unlink.php) vai remover o arquivo correspondente ao caminho.

[Fonte](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unlink.php#109971)

Comment: Funcionou perfeito, obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o [**`glob`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) como o @JuniorNunes sugeriu, ainda sim `glob` é case-sensitive (difere letras maiúsculas de minusculas), ou seja se tiver arquivos assim:

- `1.JPG`
- `2.Jpg`
- `3.jpg`

Somente o `1.JPG` será excluído, ou seja `2.Jpg` e `3.jpg` serão mantidos, o que creio que não seja o que deseja.

o ideal seria fazer assim:

```
array_map('unlink', glob('images/*.[Jj][Pp][Gg]'));
```

Com o `[Jj][Pp][Gg]` ele irá reconhecer a extensão independente se tiver qualquer letra maiúscula ou minuscula.

Comment: Boa, agora que fui reparar que o glob era case-sensitive, valeu!!! +1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, referente à minha resposta, confundir, achei que o autor queria pastar todos os `jpg`, inclusive das subpasta (foi o que eu entendi pelo comentário na pergunta). Sobre o `glob` e `preg_match`, isso é necessário quando quer filtrar os arquivos internos também.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr acho que não entendi. Olhando o seu código a sua função era recursiva, logo é glob chamado dentro de glob (para cada pasta existente), o que poderia simplificar o uso de `foreach(glob("{$dir}/*") as &$file)` para `foreach(glob("{$dir}/*.[Jj][Pp][Gg]") as &$file)`, ou estou enganado?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, dessa segunda maneira, funciona quando ele quer apagar somente os arquivos de uma pasta (ignorando subpastas). Caso ele quisesse apagar todos os arquivos (incluindo das subpastas), o ideal é usar o `glob` para listar tudo (arquivos e pastas) e depois o `preg_match` para verificar apenas a extensão. No caso dessa segunda, *não funciona para capturar os **arquivos recursivamente***, pois ele retornará apenas os arquivos "jpg", sem as subpastas.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr entendi, é verdade, mas pode simplicar muito se usar `GLOB_ONLYDIR` e mesclar dois globs, um somente dos jpg e outro somente da recursão. De qualquer fora sua regex pode causar problemas, creio que assim seria melhor `preg_match("/\.{$ext}$/i", $file)`. No geral entendi a sua proposta. Obrigado por esclarecer o/