# Apagando a pasta e não os arquivos

Tags: php

Não estou conseguindo identificar onde estou errando..

O Código abaixo, está excluindo a minha pasta uploads e é de onde está vindo os arquivos, mas na verdade eu gostaria que apagasse os arquivos de uploads/pasta e não a pasta a uploads. Alguma possível ajuda?

EDIT:
Não é apagar a pasta toda e sim os arquivos das subpastas: "uploads/subpasta/arquivo.extensao <- é o arquivo.extensao que deve ser apagado somente.

Obrigado desde já!

```
<?php
$src = 'uploads';
$dst = 'bkp/';

rcopy($src, $dst);  // Call function 
// Function to Copy folders and files       
function rcopy($src, $dst) {
    if (file_exists ( $dst ))
        rrmdir ( $dst );
    if (is_dir ( $src )) {
        mkdir ( $dst );
        $files = scandir ( $src );
        foreach ( $files as $file )
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
                rcopy ( "$src/$file", "$dst/$file" );

    } else if (file_exists ( $src ))
        copy ( $src, $dst );
                    rrmdir ( $src );
}       

// Function to remove folders and files 
function rrmdir($dir) {
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        $files = scandir($dir);
        foreach ($files as $file)
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") rrmdir("$dir/$file");
        rmdir($dir);
    }
    else if (file_exists($dir)) unlink($dir);
}
?>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como apagar arquivos dentro de uma pasta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56228/como-apagar-arquivos-dentro-de-uma-pasta)

Comment: No meu caso, eu estou querendo somente apagar os arquivos das subpastas de uploads. Não a pasta toda, como citado.Mas a partir do código acima.